# Windows programming service is unable to connect to Mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using a windows programming in c#,the windows service which I am using as to connect mysql database to fetch the data and it has to upload the data to server.But when the services is being started in my local system, the windows service is getting started first and then Mysql database service is getting started.
In this case, it is unable to connect to mysql database, so that I have to create a dependency that mysql should start first and then windows service has to start next.

How to implement the dependency code in my program,such that the clients who are using this windows service should not effect with this problem,I have do it through code that it has to be done automatically.

Comment: you could just catch the connection failed exception and wait a few seconds before trying again. Once connected, run the rest of the service as normal. If lack of connection persists for a longer period of time, indicating a bigger fault, then generate an exception and/or send a fault report email or whatever your app's normal policy is for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can set DelayedAutoStart = true for you System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller in your Installer class.